# Subharmonic functions, their critical points and values

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, morse-theory

Let $f \colon \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}_{+} \cup \left\{ 0 \right\}$ be a $C^{\infty}$ subharmonic function. Be given a compact domain $K \subset \mathbb{C}$, we let
$D_{K}(f)$ be the set of critical points of $f$ lying in $K$, $V_{K}(f)$ be the set of critical values of $f \colon K \to \mathbb{R}_{+}$.

What can be said about $D_{K}(f)$ and $V_{K}(f)$? In particular, **Do they have to be finite?**

I am sorry if this question is obvious and something I haven’t given enough thought.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Unless you change your question: Any constant function has an infinite amount of critical values and is subharmonic.

Comment: In the light of the maximum principle, you should maybe exclude constant functions. Then maybe you could at least infer sth like that critical values are saddle points/maximums.